# How can I match datetime object and Pandas date object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am having troubles trying to match a datetime obejct with a Pandas date object.

My code returns this:

IN:

```
date_ex_dividend = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['ex_dividend'], '%d.%m.%Y')
print (date_ex_dividend,type(date_ex_dividend))
```

OUT:

2018-01-03 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

IN:

```
df = pdr.data.DataReader('CIE.MC',start='2018-1-1', end='2018-12-31', data_source = "yahoo")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print (index, type(index))
```

OUT:

```
2018-01-02 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2018-01-03 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2018-01-04 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2018-01-05 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2018-01-08 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

As you can see date matches with df in 2nd row:
but when I am trying to compare dates, I got this error:

IN:

```
print (df[date_ex_dividend]==date_ex_dividend)
```

OUT:

```
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0)
```

Is this because I am trying to campare diferent classes??
Any idea to solve this?

Comment: You can probably do `df[df.index == date_ex_dividend]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
date_ex_dividend = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['ex_dividend'], '%d.%m.%Y')
```

You should do:

```
date_ex_dividend = pd.to_datetime(data['ex_dividend'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

This way it will be a proper Pandas datetime object.

Comment: Oustanding sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the dataframe you have there with a datetime. The problem is you need to compare your datetime (date_ex_dividend) with then index of your dataframe (df.index).

```
date_ex_dividend ==df.index
```

the above creates a mask, you can then use this to find the matching row(s) in the dataframe.

```
result = df[date_ex_dividend ==df.index]
print(result)
```